# MySQL : Applying index to benifit query with 4 user controlled conditions in a where clause

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

Suppose I have a simple query structure which looks like this :

```
Select columns,
FROM table
WHERE CONDITIONS
```

and I have 4 parameters: **A**, **B**, **C**, & **D** . These parameters define the search criteria. For example:

```
Select columns,
FROM table
WHERE A = 'something' AND B = 'something'
```

**OR**

```
Select columns,
FROM table
WHERE A = 'something' AND B = 'something' AND C = 'Something'
```

etc.

There can be several examples where every time I can define a different search criteria like the difference demonstrated between the two queries **mentioned above**.

Here are the different possible search combinations that I can apply to my `WHERE` CLAUSE

```
1.  WHERE A = 'something' AND B = 'something' AND  C = 'something' AND  D = 'something'
2.  WHERE A = 'something' AND B = 'something' AND  C = 'something'
3.  WHERE A = 'something' AND B = 'something'
4.  WHERE A = 'something' AND C = 'something'
5.  WHERE A = 'something' AND D = 'something'
6.  WHERE A = 'something'
7.  WHERE B = 'something' AND C = 'something' AND  D = 'something'
8.  WHERE B = 'something' AND C = 'something'
9.  WHERE B = 'something' AND D = 'something'
10. WHERE B = 'something'
11. WHERE C = 'something' AND D = 'something'
12. WHERE C = 'something'
13. WHERE D = 'something'
```

**What Indices can I define here ? keeping in mind I define the least number of indices and optimize all the search scenarios.**

The primary key defined for the table is :

```
PRIMARY KEY(A,B,C,D)
```

---

**EDIT**

DATA TYPES are as follows :

```
    A (VARCHAR)
    B (VARCHAR)
    C (INT)
    D (DATE)
```

Comment: A,B,C,D `varchar` type?

Comment: @1000111 kindly refer to the EDIT in my post

Comment: Are you maintaining separate queries for each of the possible search combinations ?

Comment: @1000111 Yes that's what I'm doing, I handle the query selection at application level.

Comment: Is it D=constant?  Or is it D BETWEEN...?  It makes a big different is designing indexes.

Comment: Some reason for not having 13 combinations, but not the other 2?

Comment: @RickJames D is always placed at the last as shown, it's a date. Sorry didn't get your last question , "not having 13 combinations, but not the other 2", sorry ? :o.

Comment: The two missing are ABD and ACD.

Comment: D last -- It does not matter in the `WHERE`, but it does matter in the `INDEX` if you are using a range (such as `BETWEEN`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Since you are maintaining separate queries for each of the possible search combinations then to the best of my knowledge you need **4 indice**s.</strike>

You already have this one `A,B,C,D` **`(PK)`**

**`A,B,C,D` index will be a use of the following search scenarios:**

```
A,B,C,D
A,B,C
A,B
A
```

**`B,C,D` index will be a use of the following search scenarios:**

```
B,C,D
B,C
B
```

**`C,D` index will be a use of the following search scenarios:**

```
C,D
C
```

**`D` index will be a use of the following search scenarios:**

```
D
```

**EDIT:**

Sorry for missing other cases. Thanks to @Rick James.

Actually the all possible search combination among the columns `A,B,C,D` are as follows:

**Length = 4**

```
1.  A,B,C,D
```

**Length = 3**

```
2.  A,B,C
3.  A,C,D
4.  A,B,D
5.  B,C,D
```

**Length = 2**

```
6.  A,B
7.  A,C
8.  A,D
9.  B,C
10. B,D
11. C,D
```

**Length = 1**

```
12. A
13. B
14. C
15. D
```

---

**Index Required (8):**

```
A,B,C,D 
A,C,D 
A,B,D
B,C,D
A,D
B,D
C,D
D
```

---

**Note:** There are certain cases where multiple indexes can enroll to contribute. But the decision is left to the `optimizer` and the `optimizer` alone decides which index to use.

Comment: I'll  accept this answer after testing it. Is this optimal to use different queries or can this be handled with one query too along with indexing ?

Comment: I think writing separate queries is cumbersome but once you do you can take advantage from that.

Comment: No.  None of those is "best" for A,C.

Comment: thanks rick. I will take care of the answer later @RickJames

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps 6 is the minimum to handle all 13 cases, each optimally:

```
The PK takes care of 1,2,3,6.
INDEX(A,C) takes care of 4.
INDEX(D,A) takes care of 5,13.
INDEX(B,C,D) takes care of 7,8,10.
INDEX(B,D) takes care of 9. (and 10)
INDEX(C,D) takes care of 11,12
```

In general, when threatened with a huge number of "needed" indexes, stop with 2 columns.  For example, `INDEX(B,C)` will be nearly as good as `INDEX(B,C,D)`.  With that in mind, I would pick these 6 for the 15 combos:

AB;BC;CD;DA;AC;BD (Note that AB is already covered by the PK, so don't add it.)

*Caveat:* Your question states `=` on all tests.  If, instead, you use a "range" (`BETWEEN`, `<`, etc) or `IN` or `OR` for any of the `WHERE` parts, this answer becomes less optimal.